# number format exception while converting substring part

Tags: java

I'm trying to make an auto increment function that each time user create table `Departmenent_id(varchar)` is incremented and the id i have given A1,A2..... so what i do in my autoincrement() that i use  the list of ,result getting from `select Dept_id from Department`  and try to separate the integer part from this and adding to `TreeSet` collection and taking out largest element and adding to first part of String but problem i face when i take out the substring of string  like `9` and parsing it into integer i m getting `number format exception`. Why am I getting this problem my function code is right here

```
    private String autoIncreament() {
    String id = null;
    String num = null;
    String result = "SELECT DEPARTMENT_ID FROM  Department";
    TreeSet<Integer> treeSet = new TreeSet<Integer>();
    List<Map<String, Object>> result1 = getJdbcTemplate().queryForList(
            result);
    for (Map<String, Object> map : result1) {
        id = (String) map.get("DEPARTMENT_ID");
        System.out.println("id=" + id);
        num = id.substring(1);
        int number = Integer.parseInt(num);
        treeSet.add(number);

    }

    Integer in = treeSet.pollLast();
             int c=in.intValue();
               c++;
    id = id +c ;
    /* System.out.println("jcak="+rowSet.getRow()); */
    return id;
}
```

my exception details

```
    19 Dec, 2012 11:25:14 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@5d764be1: startup date [Wed Dec 19 11:25:14 IST 2012]; root of context hierarchy
19 Dec, 2012 11:25:14 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [mybeans.xml]
19 Dec, 2012 11:25:14 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@7b5a6029: defining beans [dataSource,employeeDaoImpl,departmentdao]; root of factory hierarchy
19 Dec, 2012 11:25:14 AM org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource setDriverClassName
INFO: Loaded JDBC driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
ankur=com.nousinfo.tutorial.employee.model.Department@7eb1cc87
id=9
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at com.nousinfo.tutorial.employee.dao.impl.DepartmentDAOImpl.autoIncreament(DepartmentDAOImpl.java:113)
    at com.nousinfo.tutorial.employee.dao.impl.DepartmentDAOImpl.getDepartment(DepartmentDAOImpl.java:47)
    at AccessClass.main(AccessClass.java:34)
```

Comment: Are you sure you are extracting numbers only?

Comment: This is not a good logic for incrementing sequence number. Use separate table for ID Generator. If you use JPA, you can use TableGenerator

Comment: You can have a Table `IDGenerator` columns 1.TableName 2.LastSeqNumber. Increment last seq number whenever you add new row

Comment: I don't think your exception from parseInt line. Please post your full output ant exception

Comment: @vels4j  but i  m not using jpa i have to build my own logic thats why i paste my question here ,why i m getting number format exception while converting it  into integer plz help me out

Comment: provide your exception stack trace and output

Comment: @smit ya  i have to extract no and after increment that no i m adding it to string

Comment: did you try printing num value before parsing it?

Comment: @henrycharles If its exact integer then there is no way that it will throw numberfomat exception

Comment: If you see in the exception Id value you printed is `9`.And you are trying to do operation on empty string. May be that's the reason you getting that exception.

Comment: @henrycharles, What is your id print value?why are u using substring(1), can you explain me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using normal jdbc, java has provided the support to read the key.

```
connection = getConnection();
String sql = "insert into table1 (col1,Rcol2) values (?, ?)";
ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql, new String[] {"colKEY"});
ps.setString(1, col1Val);
ps.setString(2, col2Val);
ps.executeUpdate();     

rs = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
if (rs.next()){
    colKey = new Integer(rs.getInt(1));
}
connection.commit();
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: i m not using normal jdbc i m using spring

Answer (score 1):

This could be the line causing NumberFormatException.

```
int number = Integer.parseInt(num);
```

The easiest way to see what's going wrong is to print the `num` before this line, it may not be a number.

EDIT (after question was modified) - Empty string ("") cannot be converted to an integer.

On a side note, you can ID generators for any serious use-case / application.

Answer (score 0):

exception says it all:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

you are trying to parse empty string to int

if your input string 9 and you are taking substring from index 1 you are getting empty string

Answer (score 0):

```
 num = id.substring(1);

it shows start index from 1. If your value is "7" then it will get "".
```

Change with it

```
  num = id.substring(0);         

 try{
       int number = Integer.parseInt(num);

 } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
   ex.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Comment: The description of the post is clearly misleading as OP shows printed value as `9`.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is your are not committing sequence number with prefix. Simply the following logic may this help you

1. Get number of rows in table `Department` by `"select count(*) from department"`
2. then `return "A"+(numberOfRows+1) ;`